# Equivalent definitions of holomorphic between $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, analytic-functions

There are a few equivalent definitions of holomorphic functions between Banach spaces.  Let $F:\mathbb{C}^n \to \ell^2$ be a function where $\ell^2$ denotes the Hilbert space of sequences $(a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|^2 < \infty$.  Consider the following two definitions of holomorphic:

1. $F = (F_1, F_2,\ldots)$ is said to be (weakly) holomorphic if for every continuous linear functional $T$ on $\ell^2$, $T \circ f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^n$
2. $F = (F_1, F_2,\ldots)$ is said to be holomorphic if each $F_k$ is holomorphic and the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |F_k|^2$ converges uniformly on all compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n.$

How do we show that the two definitions are equivalent.  I can prove that definition 2 implies definition 1:

Proof that 2) implies 1):

Since $\ell^2$ is a Hilbert space with complex inner product given by
$$
\langle a, b \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \overline{a_k}b_k,
$$
$\ell^2 = (\ell^2)^*$.  So it suffices to show that for every function $F$ holomorphic in the sense of definition 2 and every $a \in \ell^2$, that
$$
\langle a, F\rangle(\cdot) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \overline{a_k}f_k(\cdot)
$$
converges uniformly on compact subsets of  $\mathbb{C}^n$.  This is immediate by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality since $\left|\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} \overline{a_k}f_k(z)\right|$ is bounded above by
$$
 ||a||_{\ell^{2}} \sqrt{\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} |f_k|^2}
$$
which can be made arbitrarily small on any compact set by taking $N$ sufficiently large.